# Trying to update a user profile in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like it to be possible to update the portfolie_site field and the profile_image, so I created the ProfileUpdateForm but I'm having problems saving the inputs

I would love some help, I have no idea what I'm doing. :)

## Update!

#### NOW: So I can update the urlfield, but not the imagefield

I updated the code and added print to see more clearly what is happening.
This is what I'm getting in the command-line now:

#### Command-line

```
GET profile.html
[17/Oct/2019 11:12:51] "GET /accounts/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1600
POST sending you back HOME
[17/Oct/2019 11:12:59] "POST /accounts/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Oct/2019 11:12:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1100
```

## Models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='swap_me/profile_image',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

## Forms.py

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Profile
        fields = ("portfolio_site","profile_image")
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["portfolio_site"].label = "Site"
        self.fields["profile_image"].label = "Image"
```

## Views.py

```
@login_required
def profile_update(request):
    user = request.user
    form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=user.profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("POST sending you back HOME")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            print("error")
    else:
        print("GET profile.html")
    context = {
        "profile_updateform":form,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

## Profile.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profile_updateform.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Update">
  </form>
{% else %}
  <h1>You need to login!</h1>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? It might be helpful if you could go over [how to ask the perfect question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to follow some of the steps to make it easier for us to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should save the model using the form instead:

```
@login_required
def profile_update(request):
    user = request.user
    form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST or None, initial={'profile_image': user.profile.profile_image,
                                                      'portfolio_site': user.profile.portfolio_site})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            print("Fist me daddy!")
    else:
        print(request.method)
    context = {
        "profile_updateform":form,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

### Update

When you call `form.save()`, the form object attempts to update the existing model if you have an instance defined, otherwise it tries to create one; since you are manually adding data using `initial`, the form is trying to a create a new `Profile` row in your database, but it doesn't have the required `user_id` (which is the `user` field), and throws that error.  To fix this, you should use `instance` in your form instead of `initial`:

```
form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=user.profile)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying:

IntegrityError at /accounts/profile/
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id

do you know what it means?

Comment: @Martin yeah, sorry.  I added an update that should explain it and fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this, I updated the code, but it still doesn't work. The View sends me to profile.html where I can see and fill out the form and when I submit the form it sends me back to the homepage without error. But it still doesn't update the profile. (I added print and some of the command-line so you can see)